# Save button in theme customization page stays disabled

Tags: settings-api, theme-customizer

Ok here's the scenario: 
I have added a custom section to an existing theme so that it shows up in the theme customization page (customize.php).
The problem I am having is that I don't know how to notify wordpress when changes are made in my custom control. I guess I am missing something in my code because it should do it in automatic?

Here is some sample code:

```
$wp_customize->add_section('my_section', 
    array(
        'title' => 'My title',
        'description' => 'My description',
        'priority' => 201
    )
);

$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'my_setting',
    array(
        'default' => '',
        'type' => 'option',
        'transport' => 'postMessage'
    )
);

$wp_customize->add_control(
    new My_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'my_control',
        array(
            'label'    => 'My label',
            'settings' => 'my_setting',
            'section'  => 'my_section'
        )
    )
);
```

Note that `My_Control` is a class which enqueues additional js/css files and renders my sortable list.
I am storing my model in **an array** rather than using multiple settings; I add my model to the page using the `wp_localize_script` function.

Answer (score 0):

Real-time updating is achieved with JavaScript. Is your .js code working? The Codex has great examples and I think Otto has a defacto post about it somewhere on Google.

This has everything you need:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API

Comment: Yes, my js code is working properly, I'll have a thorough look at the documentation. Thanks for answering by the way

Answer (score 0):

Wait, why use `transport => postMessage`? That's for handling the communication between the control and a JS script.

You should just use `transport => refresh`, this way WordPress will refresh itself on change on the input.